# Google Analytics APIを使ってイベント(行動情報)を取るには？

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

Google Analytics APIを使ってanalyticsの**イベント情報**は取れますか？

Pythonを使って、Reporting API v4を使って、ページビューの情報を取得できることは確認できました。

しかし、イベント(詳細は添付ファイルにて)情報が取れません。
というより、そもそも、APIでイベント情報が取れるか、調べてみましたがわかりません。

もし知っている方がいましたらご教示お願い致します。

参考にしたサイト
Reporting API v4
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet?hl=ja

[image: APIで取りたい情報]

Answer (score 0):

自己解決！
以下のように「dimensions」のところに「ga:eventAction」を追加することにより解決しました。

ドキュメント
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/?hl=ja

```
def get_report(analytics, next_page_token="0"):

request_body = {
    "reportRequests": [{
        "viewId": VIEW_ID,
        "pageSize": 100000,
        "pageToken": next_page_token,
        "dateRanges": [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
        "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:pageviews"},{"expression": "ga:users"},{"expression": "ga:avgTimeOnPage"}],
        #"metrics": [{"expression": "ga:users"}]
        "dimensions": [{"name": "ga:pagePath"}, {"name": "ga:pageTitle"},{"name": "ga:eventAction"}],
        "orderBys": [{"fieldName": "ga:pageviews", "sortOrder": "DESCENDING"}]
    }]
}
return analytics.reports().batchGet(body=request_body).execute()
```